# Errno 13 Permission denied: '/files' while trying to execute pytorch script

Tags: permissions, torch, torchvision, ubuntu-22.04, pytorch-dataloader

I am trying to execute simple pytorch command to download MNIST dataset [script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hjgwd.png) It raises a permission error in the line 23.
[Error and permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmoU4.png)

Since I am using latest stable version of Ubuntu, I've granted permission to this py file/parent-parents of this python file:

```bash
sudo chmod -R 777 [path]
sudo chmod a+rwx [parent_dir_path]
```

I've also tried to grant permission to python3.10/site-packages folder (especially torch and torchvision). But none of them worked.

Comment: I solved my problem with ChatGPT. Thanks ChatGPT, love you.